# How do I invoke another cloud function from one cloud function in Python? (Asynchronously-I don't need the response back.)

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

PS: I was doing it synchronously by using the following in my cloud function:

```
name = "projects/project1/locations/us-central1/functions/test3"
body = {
'data': '{ "message": "Function Invoked Successfully"}'
}
result = self.google_api_service.projects().locations().functions().call(name=name, body=body).execute()
#google_api_service has it's own functions
print(result)
```

Help me out to do it asynchronously! Also please do not suggest Pub/Sub. Is there any other workaround in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to answer your question:

1. In order to make an HTTP call to a separate function you have to setup an authorization token for the request. As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#functions-bearer-token-example-python) you have to first:

> Grant the Cloud Functions Invoker (`roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`) role to the calling function identity on the receiving function. By default, this identity is `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

> And then in the calling function you have to:

> - Create a Google-signed OAuth ID token with the audience (`aud`) set to the URL of the receiving function.
> - Include the ID token in an `Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN` header in the request to the function.

**NOTE**: You can follow the code example in the same documentation link on how to include it.

2. in order for the call to be async, since you don't care for the result, you can call do it by using multiprocessing pool, which could look like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
    
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 1)
p.apply_async(requests.get, ['YOUR_FUNCTION_URL'])
```

Comment: Was getting forbidden when trying to do requests.get my function URL.

Comment: I then tried to set up the Authorization. But that throws an exception as requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='metadata', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://us-central1-project1.cloudfunctions.net/function-12 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001BC21548B88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: try it without the async part, so we can check if the authentication itself has worked.